# How to find size of alien struct in sbcl?

Tags: common-lisp, ffi, sbcl

I'm trying to get the size of alien struct in SBCL (to make data buffer of proper size for alien function). In C or Pascal sizeof() do the same work. My approach is:

```
(define-alien-type MY-STRUCT
(struct MY-STRUCT
        (MY-FIELD (array char 30))))

(defmacro size-of (type) 
    (let ((x (gensym)))
        `(let ((,x (make-alien (array ,type 2))))
             (- (sb-sys:sap-int (alien-sap (deref (deref ,x) 1)))
                (sb-sys:sap-int (alien-sap (deref (deref ,x) 0)))))))

(size-of MY-STRUCT) ;; => 30
```

Is there a proper way to get size of alien struct in SBCL?

Comment: `(alien-size my-struct :bytes)` should work.

Comment: @jkiiski,  Thanks! It works)